# Why can I not destructure this tuple when iterating over a HashMap?

Tags: rust

I'm just learning rust and am working on an easy /r/dailyprogrammer task.  Here's some code:

```
type ToDoList = HashMap<String, bool>;

fn print(list: &ToDoList) {
    let mut max_len: usize = 0;
    for (item, _) in list.iter() {
        max_len = max(max_len, item.len());
    }
    let end = format!("+---{}-+", 
        iter::repeat("-").take(max_len).collect::<String>());

    println!("{}", end);
    for (item, done) in list.iter() {
        let line = format!("| {0} {1}{2} |", 
            if done {"☑"} else {"☐"}, 
            item,
            iter::repeat("-")
                .take(max_len - item.len())
                .collect::<String>()
        );
        println!("{:?}", (item, done));
    }
    println!("{}", end);
}
```

I'm getting this error from rustc:

```
error: type mismatch resolving `<std::collections::hash::map::Iter<'_,
 collections::string::String, bool> as core::iter::Iterator>::Item ==
 (_, bool)`:  expected &-ptr,
     found bool [E0271]
 todolist.rs:19     for (item, done) in list.iter() {
 todolist.rs:20         let line = format!("| {0} {1}{2} |", 
 todolist.rs:21             if done {"☑"} else {"☐"},  
 todolist.rs:22             item,
 todolist.rs:23             iter::repeat("-")
 todolist.rs:24                 .take(max_len - item.len())
                ...
 todolist.rs:24:21: 24:31 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
 todolist.rs:24                 .take(max_len - item.len())
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~ note: in expansion of format_args! <std macros>:2:26: 2:57 note: expansion site <std
 macros>:1:1: 2:61 note: in expansion of format!
 todolist.rs:20:14: 26:4 note: expansion site error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

It seems like both of these are related to the same issue that somehow calling `list.iter()` is trying to give me a tuple of `(_, String, bool)` instead of just `(String, bool)`.  Why is that happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is not very readable. What is happening is that `done` is of type `&bool` since you are iterating in a non-owning way.

> type mismatch resolving `<std::collections::hash::map::Iter<'_, collections::string::String, bool> as core::iter::Iterator>::Item == (_, bool)`:

Basically you need to check what the actual type of [`std::collections::hash::map::Iter::Item`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/collections/hash_map/struct.Iter.html) is. As you can see in the docs it is `(&'a K, &'a V)`.

Changing

```
for (item, done) in list.iter() {
```

to

```
for (item, &done) in list.iter() {
```

will fix your issue.

What causes this confusion, is Rust's type inference. Since you are using `done` as the argument to an `if`, Rust knows for a fact that it needs to be of type `bool`. So it goes backwards from there to the assignment of the `done`-binding until it finds some other concrete type. In other languages it would probably have been the other way around, and the error would have occurred in the if-condition.

---

As a side-note, in your first iteration `for (item, _) in list.iter() {` you are only interested in the keys of the `HashMap`. You can use `for item in list.keys()` for a more concise loop.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems like both of these are related to the same issue that somehow calling list.iter() is trying to give me a tuple of (_, String, bool) instead of just (String, bool). Why is that happening?

You are right that both are related to the original error, but wrong about the error:

> ```
> (_, bool)`:  expected &-ptr,
> ```

You get a `(_, bool)` tuple whereas the compiler expected to see a tuple of references `(&_, &bool)` to something. This `_` could well be a `String` (or `&String`) in the compiler message, so this not the issue.

The issue is that you are expecting a *value* where the compiler expects a *reference*, this stems from the fact that `iter()` returns *references* to the underlying elements of the collection iterated upon and the simple fix is to change how you match:

```
for (item, &done) in &list {
}
```

As can be seen in the docs:

```
impl<'a, K, V> Iterator for Iter<'a, K, V>
type Item = (&'a K, &'a V)
```

The other way around would be to bind `done` to `&bool` and then dereference it before use:

```
for (item, done) in &list {
    if *done { ... } else { ... }
}
```